# Flutter how to get province and cities?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am searching for plugin from which I can get province and cities for one country only. Mean I dont want to select country.

I have found this plugin which is good but issue is its asking for country pick.

https://pub.dev/packages/restcountries

Comment: I don't understand well your request: `I can get province and cities for one country only. Mean I dont want to select country`. There is a contradiction. Can you explain it better? What country are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

From the examples at this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/restcountries/example)

> List cities = await api.getCities(
> countryCode: 'id', region: 'Jawa Timur', keyword: 'mal');

Since you already know which country you want to get the cities from, just assign that country's code to `countryCode`,

For example, if you want `cities` of United States with keyword `ar`,

```
List<City> cities = await api.getCities(
  countryCode: 'us', keyword: 'ar');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the above answer. Given a County you could make a series of calls to get the data set you want.

`countries = await api.getCountries();` -- Will return the countries the service has, then search through the list to find the one you want.

`regions = await api.getRegions(countryCode: 'id');` -- Will then get you the regions for the country, I'm assuming you'll get the code from the first call, otherwise a good place to start with the code would be to use the the IEEE country codes.

[Check Them Out Here](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countrycodes.htm)

Finally use the regions you got to get the cities;

`await api.getCities(countryCode: 'id', region: 'Jawa Timur');`

Bringing it all together you'd have something like this... (I have not looked at the API specification so the guess at a memeber in that loop "region.name" is likely incorrect)

```
import 'package:restcountries/restcountries.dart';

void main() async {
  var api = RestCountries.setup(Platform.environment['API_KEY']);
  List<Country> countries;
  List<Region> regions;
  List<City> cities;
  countries = await api.getCountries();
  // Search here for your country
  regions = await api.getRegions(countryCode: '*YOUR COUNTRY CODE HERE*');
  // Now we loop to get cities in every region.
  regions.forEach((region){
    cities += await api.getCities(countryCode: '*YOUR COUNTRY CODE HERE*', region: region.name);
  });
  print(regions);
  print(cities);
}
```